# ansible-vault error - "Vault format unhexlify error: Odd-length string"

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-vault

I am using ansible-napalm and trying to write a simple playbook to pull facts from network devices.
I want to encrypt the passwords with ansible-vault, however regardless of what I try I keep getting the error: 
    Vault format unhexlify error: Odd-length string

I initially was trying this in bash under the Windows subsystem for Linux and I thought this may be the issue so I recreated everything on a centos VM and still run into the same issue.

I have tried using encrypt-string to embed the encrypted pw directly into the playbook.
I have also tried encrypting the file and calling the variable. Both methods give the same error.

I found this issue: [Ansible-vault errors with "Odd-length string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787412/ansible-vault-errors-with-odd-length-string)
And I thought the issue was to do with CRLF line terminators so I sorted that and made sure all files were ASCII text but this still gives the same errors.

My code is below, any help would be majorly appreciated because I am pulling my hair out!

```
---

- name: napalm_facts
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: get facts from device
      napalm_get_facts:
        hostname: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        username:  'admin'
        password: "{{ napalm_password }}"
        dev_os: 'ios'
      register: result

    - name: print results
      debug: msg="{{ result }}"
```

I've tried the below methods, for reference.

```
ansible-vault encrypt vars/vaultpw.yml
```

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string password123 --ask-vault-pass
```

Comment: Have you considered using their "inline" style, [as described here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/vault.html#use-encrypt-string-to-create-encrypted-variables-to-embed-in-yaml)? Another advantage of the inline style is that it offers the playbook reader an idea of what variables are defined therein, which `ansible-vault encrypt vars/the_whole_file.yml` does not

Comment: Also, can you reproduce your error using, quite literally, `password123` as you have posted in your question? I will help us understand exactly what circumstances you are getting that error

Comment: So I tried to literally use `password123` as you suggested and I get the following error.

`fatal: [Test_Lab_Switch]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to pass options to module, they must be JSON serializable`

I think this is something different however, so I will try to solve this error and post an update.

Comment: So I managed to get a bit further.
I can now run the playbook and it fails with the following error.
`cannot connect to device: Authentication failure: unable to connect cisco_ios x.x.x.x:22\nAuthentication failed`

Running with -vvv gives the following output:
`"password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER"`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this sorted by taking suggestions from this thread: [Inline encrypted variable not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567580/inline-encrypted-variable-not-json-serializable)
Thanks for the reply at first, it put me on the right path with getting this sorted.